# IEnumerable in Model observable

Tags: c#, wpf, ienumerable, observablecollection

I am in a situation where I have to use a existing model which I am not allowed to change the existing Properties.

```
public class Car : ModelBase
{
    private string _model;
    public string Model
    {
        get { return _model; }
        set { this.Update(x => x.Model, () => _model= value, _model, value); }
    }

    private IEnumerable<Person> _allowedDrivers;
    public IEnumerable<Person> AllowedDrivers
    {
        get { return _allowedDrivers; }
        set { this.Update(x => x.AllowedDrivers, () => _allowedDrivers=value, _allowedDrivers, value); }
    }
}
```

Now we recently started implementing a WPF UI and I need to use these existing models. Is there any way I can use the IEnumerable and let it work like a ObservableCollection without changing it really? What are my options.

The thing is I remove a AllowedDriver and then add a AllowedDriver and the UI is not updating at all. This is logical, I then made(for testing purposes) the IEnumerable an ObservableCollection and then the UI works. Do I have any other options in keep using the IEnumerable but gets updated?

Comment: `IEnumerable` does not know anything about counting, adding and removing. Theoretically it could be an endless collection. Maybe you could create a derived class?

Comment: `public class Car () : Modelbase` ... **`()`** ? What does `Update(....)` ? Has `Modelbase` anything like `System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged` or `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: _"Do I have any other options in keep using the IENumerable but gets updated?"_ -- questions taking the form of "any other options" are invariably too broad. Of _course_ you have other options. But whether they apply in your case, we have no way to know. Regardless, any option you take won't be as efficient as using `ObservableCollection<T>`. Note that as long as the object set for the `AllowedDrivers` is in fact an `ObservableCollection<T>`, it should work, even if the _property type_ is `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: this is a perfectly clear question with a perfectly clear answer as Mihai Alexandru-lonut posted. This kind of moderation in the form of "everything without an answer like = 2 has to be closed" sucks, SO wouldn't be the same if that was made since the beginning.

Comment: @Ignacio:  _"this is a perfectly clear question with a perfectly clear answer"_ -- the question is clear, but it doesn't have **a** clear answer, it has many. There are already two completely different ones posted, and no shortage of other possible ones. _"SO wouldn't be the same if that was made since the beginning"_ -- first of all, SO already isn't _"the same"_. Secondly, there are **many** questions from the "early days" that would not be tolerated today, for good reason. It's why and how the question-asking guidelines have in fact changed over the years.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: any valid answer helps the op and that's the main reason SO exists isn't it? So someone has the need of knowing something, SO people can help him but he should ask it because there are different possible answers ... rock solid ...

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia: _"any valid answer helps the op" -- that is simply not true. The OP has some specific goal in mind. Any valid answer that does not fulfill their goal, does _not_ help them. _"that's the main reason SO exists isn't it?"_ -- also very wrong. Frankly, helping the people who post question is simply a side-effect. The primary goal is to build a collection of useful questions with answers to those questions. Poorly-defined, vague questions are not useful and neither is answering such questions.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: ok, we have a very different point on view regarding "helping the people who post question is simply a side-effect". To me it's the main reason of the site and that's why I'm a member, to help real people asking questions about real problems not to build a possible reference for a possible (or not) future use.

Comment: @Ignacio: you're welcome to your opinion. But, it flies in the fact of _facts_. The people who made Stack Overflow get to decide what the _purpose_ of the site is. And they say otherwise. I.e. [_"...to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming"_](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). See also discussions like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292175/what-is-the-purpose-of-stack-overflow and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal.

Comment: Isnt this what view models are for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply *assign* an ObservableCollection to the AllowedDrivers property and operate on that collection:

```
var drivers = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
car.AllowedDrivers = drivers;
```

Now adding a new Person to the `drivers` collection will actually update the UI, because a bound UI element does a runtime check whether a collection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`:

```
drivers.Add(new Person(...));
```

---

The above of course assumes that your `ModelBase.Update` method isn't doing anything strange, and eventually assigns the `value` argument of the property setter to its backing field `_allowedDrivers` so that the property getter returns the collection instance that was passed to the setter.

---

EDIT: If possible at all, it would make sense to change the Car class to use `ICollection<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public class Car : ModelBase
{
    ...

    private ICollection<Person> _allowedDrivers;
    public ICollection<Person> AllowedDrivers
    {
        get { return _allowedDrivers; }
        set { this.Update(x => x.AllowedDrivers, () => _allowedDrivers=value, _allowedDrivers, value); }
    }
}
```

You could then still assign an ObservableCollection, but get rid of the `drivers` variable:

```
car.AllowedDrivers = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
car.AllowedDrivers.Add(new Person(...));
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way I can use the IEnumerable and let it work like a
>   ObservableCollection without changing it really?

You can create another **class** which inherits your `Car` class. Since your `ObservableCar` inherits `Car` class you have access to `AllowedDrivers` property.

So, you can declare your desired `observable` collection and initialize with an observable collection converted from `AllowedDrivers`. This initialization should be inside `get`.

```
public class ObservableCar: Car {
    public ObservableCar(){
         _observableAllowedDriver = new ObservableCollection<Person>(AllowedDrivers);
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _observableAllowedDriver;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> ObservableAllowedDriver
    {
        get { return _observableAllowedDriver; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyones input. I solved it via making/casting the IEnumerable to an ObservableCollection.

Like so:

```
  public class Car : ModelBase
  {

    public Car()
    {
        AllowedDrivers = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    }

    private string _model;
    public string Model
    {
        get { return _model; }
        set { this.Update(x => x.Model, () => _model= value, _model, value); }
    }

    private IEnumerable<Person> _allowedDrivers;
    public IEnumerable<Person> AllowedDrivers
    {
        get { return _allowedDrivers; }
        set { this.Update(x => x.AllowedDrivers, () => _allowedDrivers=value, _allowedDrivers, value); }
    }
}
```

And then using it in my viewmodel or so I use it like this:

```
 var allowedDrivers = (ObservableCollection<Person>)Car.AllowedDrivers;
 allowedDrivers.Add(person)
```

Comment: Note that for being able to add elements, it is sufficient to cast to `ICollection`, like `((ICollection<Person>)Car.AllowedDrivers).Add(person)`. It would make much sense to change the view model to contain `public ICollection<Person> AllowedDrivers { get; set; }`. You could then simply write `Car.AllowedDrivers.Add(person)`.